# Decoding of encoded text only works partially (he)

Tags: regex, decode

The data retrived from the server comes encoded in what I believe to be ISO-8859-1.
After using the "he" library to decode the retrieved text, it only decodes part of the string.

```
**Retrieved encoded text** - A edi&Atilde;&sect;&Atilde;&pound;o &quot;Arquivo LdoD&quot; &Atilde;&copy; uma edi&Atilde;&sect;&Atilde;&pound;o
```

**Expected after decode** - A edição "Arquivo LdoD" é uma edição

**Actual result of decode** - A ediÃ§Ã£o "Arquivo LdoD" Ã© uma ediÃ§Ã£o

React Code:

```
import he from 'he'

.
.
.

useEffect(() => {
            getVirtualEditionList(props.acronym)
                .then(res => {
                    setEditionData(res.data.sortedInterpsList)

                    console.log(res.data.synopsis) //A edi&Atilde;&sect;&Atilde;&pound;o ...
                    console.log(he.decode(res.data.synopsis)) //A ediÃ§Ã£o "Arquivo LdoD" Ã© ...
                    setSynopsis(he.decode(res.data.synopsis))
                    setTitle(he.decode(res.data.title))
                    
                    setLoading(false)
                })
        }
        
    }, [props.page])
```

I had to place the retrived string in code since Stackoverflow was already decoding it's contents, this decoding resulted in the same value I get when i decode in my React application.

Is there anyway to fix this, maybe a way to manually decode the rest of the text that the "he" library wasn't able to decode? The problem seems to be with the Portuguese/latin characters - é, ç, ã, á.

SOLVED:
Encoded text to **win1252** then decoded it to **utf-8**:

```
let decoded = iconv.encode(he.decode(res.data.synopsis), 'win1252');
setSynopsis(decoded.toString())
```

Comment: A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Sorry, I have no clue of its origin and the simplest understandable example is in Python `'A ediÃ§Ã£o "Arquivo LdoD" Ã© uma ediÃ§Ã£o'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` which returns `'A edição "Arquivo LdoD" é uma edição'`.

Comment: @JosefZ thank you for your answer, it works! I encoded to windows-1252 and decoded the result of that to utf-8, just like you did, but in JavaScript

Comment: Please feel free to self-answer the question and consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) (after a required period).   [See this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not Windows-1252?  It uses ranges not defined in ISO-8859-1, the "Smart quote" is particularly evil.